# Service Specific Error: 48 when trying to start MongoDB via Windows CMD

Tags: mongodb

After installing MongoDB for Windows, I ran `net start MongoDB` from command prompt and got `A service specific error occurred: 48.`

The mongo documentation only specifies that error 48 means "A newly started mongod or mongos could not start listening for incoming connections, due to an error."

Any ideas?

SOLUTION - Port 27017 (the default Mongo port) was currently in use. In my case, I was still running a docker container on 27017. After stopping the container, I was able to start Mongo successfully.

Comment: Please check if port 27017 is being used by some other service. To check open command prompt as administrator and run `netstat -a -b`.

Comment: @AKSHAYJAIN this worked thanks! I had forgotten to stop my docker container